# Filtragem Django de ocorências por timestamp

Tags: python, aplicação-web, django, lógica

Eu estou tendo um problema lógico ao tentar realizar uma filtragem de dados em django. Conforme o código abaixo, estou tentando realizar uma filtragem de um objeto dentro do meu banco de dados:

```py
class UserActivityQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def today(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        today_starts = timezone.make_aware(datetime.combine(now,time.min))
        today_ends = timezone.make_aware(datetime.combine(now,time.max))
        return self.filter(timestamp__gte=today_ends,timestamp__lte=today_starts)

    def current(self,user=None):
        if user is None:
            return self
        return self.filter(user=user).order_by("-timestamp").first()
```

Então, para o código em questão utlizei-me de uma filtragem do timestamp por gte e lte para pegar um espaço de tempo referente ao inicio e ao final do dia respectivamente.

Assim sendo, como resolver o problema de nenhum objeto estar sendo retornado?

Comment: Não me parece que estejas a chamar essa parte da view que partilhaste. Deverias usar essa queryset dentro de um `model.Manager`, não diretamente como estás a fazer. Dessa forma devia retornar um erro.

Comment: Sim. Realmente são saídas de pontos diferentes. Estou apenas a mostrar que existem registros feitos nas últimas 24 horas e que a falha não está no banco

Comment: Edita a pergunta e adiciona a parte relevante do models.py e views.py para te poder ajudar.

Comment: eu fazeria isso como uma propriedade do model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, para a resolução do problema apresentado e após várias análises e testes, realizei apenas uma modificação e a filtragem por timestamp funcionou sem maiores problemas. No código referente a filtragem, bastou alterar o `return`, separando os filtros, conforme segue a função alterada  no arquivo `models.py`:

```py
class UserActivityQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def today(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        today_starts = timezone.make_aware(datetime.combine(now,time.min))
        today_ends = timezone.make_aware(datetime.combine(now,time.max))
        return self.filter(timestamp__gte=today_start).filter(timestamp__lte=today_end)
```

Já, para a visualização da query, foi alterado dentro do arquivo `views.py` a função `get` da classe `UserActivityView(View)` de forma a apresentar a quantidade de eventos por meio do seguinte código:

```py
 def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(UserActivity.objects.all().count())
        print(UserActivity.objects.all().today().count())

        all_activity  =UserActivity.objects.all().today().recent()

        context = {
            "all_activity": all_activity,
        }
        return render(request, "timeclock/users-activity-view.html", context)
```

Sendo a função `recent()` apenas uma filtragem para organizar o resultado pelo timestamp por meio da seguinte filtragem: `.filter("-timestamp")` e a chamada de classe UserActivity o modelo que foi criado dentro de `models.py` para atender à demanda.

Para mais informações, acesse o repositório de tal projeto no GitHub, clicando [aqui](https://github.com/Wanghley/Raspberry-Home-Server)